# Add horizontal space in acronym environment to put the descriptions in line

Tags: spacing, acronyms

As an appendix, I have a list of abbreviations in a seperate chapter (the tex-file is called "Glossar") like this:

```
\chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\begin{acronym}\itemsep8pt
\acro{AI}       {\emph{Artificial Intelligence}, zu Deutsch: Künstliche Intelligenz}
\acro{CNN}      {\emph{Convolutional Neural Network}, zu Deutsch etwa: Faltendes neuronales Netzwerk}
\acro{DNN}      {\emph{Deep Neural Network}, zu Deutsch: Tiefes neurales Netzwerk}
\end{acronym}
```

It's includes like the following:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap, deutsch]{i-studis}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\makeindex                      
\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{Titel}
    \mytitlepage
    \newpage
    \endgroup
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \frontmatter 
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \input{chapters/Vorwort}        
    \tableofcontents                        
    \listoffigures                          
    \listoftables                           
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \mainmatter                             
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \input{chapters/Chapter1}
    % ...
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \backmatter                             
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \bibliographystyle{geralpha}        
    \bibliography{literatur}    
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \printindex                             
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{appendix}                        
        \include{chapters/Glossar}  
        \include{chapters/B}
    \end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

I looks like this:
[image]

I would like to have the descriptions in line. Or with other words: Add some horizontal space, so that the descriptions are vertically in line, like this:

[image]

I already did some search but found only results for `\newacronym` or on how to add vertical space between the items.

Comment: Can anyone tell me, why I keep getting downvotes for my questions? I want to improve. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the optional parameter of the `acronym` environment.

> The standard format of the acronym list is a `\description`
> environment. If you pass an optional parameter to the acronym
> environment, the width of the acronym-column will be fitted to the
> width of the given parameter (which should be the longest acronym).
> For example, if HBCI is the longest acronym used, the list should
> start with`\begin{acronym}[HBCI]`     (page#4 of the package document)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{acronym} 
                  
\begin{document}
 
 \begin{appendix} 
  \chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
  
  \begin{acronym}[MMMM] % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \acro{AI}       {\emph{Artificial Intelligence}, zu Deutsch: Künstliche Intelligenz}
    \acro{CNN}      {\emph{Convolutional Neural Network}, zu Deutsch etwa: Faltendes neuronales Netzwerk}
    \acro{DNN}      {\emph{Deep Neural Network}, zu Deutsch: Tiefes neurales Netzwerk}
  \end{acronym}
   \end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Oh, I see. I always missunderstood this. It never was clear to me to pass the __longest__ acronym as an argument. Thank you!